# gnuplot won't draw a function sqrt(2/10)*sin((3.14/10)*x)

Tags: gnuplot

Gnuplot won't seem to draw a function:

```
sqrt(2/10)*sin((3.14/10)*x)
```

Could anyone tell me why. I tried to draw it in [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282/10%29%2asin%28%283.14/10%29%2ax%29%20) and it worked compleetely fine there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the `2/10` is computed as integer division and zeros everything else out.

Change it to:

```
sqrt(2.0/10.0)*sin((3.14/10.0)*x)
```

Or:

```
sqrt(0.2)*sin(0.314*x)
```

Comment: This worked! But why would a ploting program like gnuplot wouldn't have this integrated. This is weird. Gnuplot is actually quite weak it seems.

Comment: This is not unique to Gnuplot. If you look at other languages (like C, for instance), implicit type conversion makes this sorta gotcha all-too-common.